# At which point Interactive Brokers monthly fees are applied?

Tags: interactive-brokers

From [the page](https://www.interactivebrokers.co.uk/en/index.php?f=38234) I've learned that **Standard Activity Fee** is $10.

But I can't find information at which point you will be charged. I'm interested because lets say I want to transfer some amount of money into my Interactive Brokers account now and invest them in 1 year when the time will be appropriate.

Does Interactive Brokers company charges you after account is created or after first money are transferred to your account or after first security bought?

**Update**

So after some research I can assume that **Waiver** section is what I'm looking for. They say:

> The first three full calendar months [7]
>
> [7] The waiver will be applicable for the first three full calendar months **after initial account funding**, regardless of whether such funding amount meets the minimum deposit required to open an account.

So, please, someone clarify, does funding in the context mean exactly when first money are transferred to an account? Or it means something different(not native speaker).

Comment: Maybe you should call them and ask? That would seem more authoritative than anything we could guess.

Comment: @dwizum if nobody answers here(maybe someone has account in IB) then I'll surely do this and post an answer here

Comment: Initial account funding means the first deposit into the account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [FAQ: Do you charge the monthly activity fee before I fund the account?](http://www.interactivebrokers.com/lib/cstools/chat?q=faq://pageId=40354229&referrer=copiedLink)

> The monthly activity fee for not meeting monthly minimums is waived for the first three full calendar months after **initial account funding**, regardless of whether such funding amount meets the minimum deposit required to open an account.

However, I mentioned in my question that I want to create an account and fund it in a year, and there may be some problems with it.

From [FAQ: How can I close an unfunded account?](http://www.interactivebrokers.com/lib/cstools/chat?q=faq://pageId=28225515&referrer=copiedLink)

> The fastest way to close an unfunded account is to enter an account
>   closure request through Client Portal/Account Management. Log in to
>   your account and click on Settings followed by Account Settings. In
>   the Configuration panel click on Configure (gear) icon next to Close
>   Account to launch the account closure page and submit your request.
>
> **Please note, however, that if you take no action the account will
>   eventually close on its own with no action required on your part.**

An account may be reopened. From [FAQ: How do I reopen a closed account?](http://www.interactivebrokers.com/lib/cstools/chat?q=faq://pageId=28238991&referrer=copiedLink)

> **REQUEST
>   REOPENING OF A CLOSED ACCOUNT**
>
> To request reopening
>   of a closed account:
>
> - Log into Client Portal/Account
>     Management
> - Select the " **Account
>     Reopen**" menu under  **Settings** followed
>     by  **Account Settings**.
>
> Once that step
>   has been completed your request will then undergo the required
>   compliance review which typically takes a few business days. If your
>   account has been closed for an extended period, you may be required to
>   initiate a new application to reflect your updated information or in
>   the event of changes to our Customer Agreement. You will receive an
>   email notice once the review has been completed and reopened accounts
>   will have 45 days to submit the initial deposit.
>
> Note that the
>   user name and password required to log in will be identical to the
>   login credentials used when the account was open.  If you do not
>   recall your user name and password you will need to contact your local
>   Client
>   Service Center via telephone so that we may verify your identity
>   and provide login access.
>
> If your account application was
>   started over 3 years ago, a new application will be
>   required.